# SQL inner join and foreign keys

Tags: database, sqlite, inner-join

I have two tables.

1. The table "persons" including "id", "fname", "lname".
2. The table "relationships" including "parent", "child" (which reference the persons.id as foreign keys)

I would like to print each parent first+last name and their children first last name.

So basically I want to have this printed:

```
George|Cameron|Eddy|Cameron       //Father-son
George|Cameron|Stephen|Cameron    //Father-son
George|Cameron|Lynda|Cameron      //Father-daughter
Elisabeth|Cameron|Eddy|Cameron    //Mother-son
Elisabeth|Cameron|Stephen|Cameron //Mother-son
Elisabeth|Cameron|Lynda|Cameron   //Mother-daughter
etc...
```

I made something like this:

```
SELECT 
    persons.fname, //parents fname  => yes, it works
    persons.lname, //parents lname  => yes, it works
    ?,             //children fname => I have no clue
    ?              //children lname => I have no clue
FROM
    persons
INNER JOIN
    relationships
ON
    persons.id = relationships.parent
```

I know I'm almost there but I just can't figure out what to type instead of the "?".
Because, basically, I need twice information from the exact same fields but once as parents and once as children.
But how can I indicate that I need the parents name for the first two arguments and the children names for the last two (as they are ALL "persons.fname" and "persons.lname")?

PS: if I may ask the most simple and straightforward way so that I can learn the basics, I would be grateful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest approach is to use table aliases.

```
SELECT 
    parent.fname, //parents fname  
    parent.lname, //parents lname  
    children.fname, //children fname 
    children.lname  //children lname 
FROM
    persons parent
INNER JOIN
    relationships
ON
    persons.id = relationships.parent 
INNER JOIN
   persons children
ON relationships.child = children.id
```

This allows you to reference the same table twice but with different aliases so you can keep them straight.

Comment: Thanks very much. It works. Something intriguing is that it's an exercice I get from a textbook that doesn't refer to aliases in any way in the theory (at least at that point). Is there a way that only uses the tables and fields names ? You answered my question and I accepted it. I was just wondering if there was something that isn't using aliases. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do it without aliases